# Unable to download .txt extension file from chrome in mac os. File content-type is "text/csv"

Tags: google-chrome, text-files, export-to-csv

I am trying to download a file having .txt extension from my application in mac chrome. I am setting content-type as "text/csv" in my code. When I downloaded that file,  its in .csv extension instead of .txt. In all other browsers its downloading as .txt file and in windows chrome also its working fine. 
I tried googling but couldn't get exact solution for this.

```
if (response != null) {
final String contentDisposition = "attachment;";
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
response.addHeader("Expires", "0");
}
```

Actual Result: File is downloading with .csv extension.
Expected Result: File have to download with .txt extension.

Comment: Why specify `csv` if you don't _want_ it to be seen as that specific on the client side? Just send it as `text/plain` then.

Comment: I want to download it in both formats(txt and csv). While downloading I will give file name with extension, so that it has to download with that extension.

Comment: Format? Changing the exposed mime type won't change your file data. You want it to be downloaded as .txt, so you should pretend it's simple text and not csv, and give it mime type `text/plain`. You can't enforce extensions; browsers have a tendency to change those to fit the mime type.

Comment: I tried "text/plain", then all browsers are only giving result as .txt files. I want both. Whatever I mentioned in file name before click on export, it has to come. This is my actual requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. Didn't you _want_ it as `.txt` only?

Comment: If I give filename as "Export.csv", it has to download as csv file. If I give name as "Export.txt", then it has to download as txt file. Now its downloading as csv only for both inputs. If I use "text/plain", its downloading as txt only for both inputs.

Comment: There is **nothing** you can do to control how that one browser will handle the CSV mime type. The only thing you can do is choose if always having `.csv` as extension is preferred over always having `.txt`. If it bothers you, go find their bug tracker and post about it there. But this is not a StackOverflow question, as it is a matter completely beyond the control of _anything_ you can change in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I have already posted in Google bug tracker. I just want to know is there any code changes will do this req, that's why I posted here. Thanks.